# CMakeLists.txt configuration - simple but stuck - library not been added to generated project

Tags: linker, include, cmake, libraries, glew

I was originally following this tutorial: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/building-your-own-c-application/
just after about half way down, from where it says "Adding a source file in a project"

I created from this my CMakeLists.txt file as so:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Cube_Project)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

add_executable(Cube
    main.cpp
)

include_directories(
    external/glfw-2.7.6/include/
    external/glm-0.9.4.0/
    external/glew-1.9.0/include/
    .
)

set(ALL_LIBS
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}
    GLFW_276
    GLEW_190
)

target_link_libraries(Cube
    ${ALL_LIBS}
)
```

but when I generate the project, I get this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lGLFW_276
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas?

I think maybe I'm not using the right names in the set(....) section?  My three libs are in a folder called external, which is the top level of the project (i.e. CMakeLists is also here).

I put a zip of the project if anyone wants to take a look at the folder layout of output XCode project structure: http://heather.sh/OpenGL_Project.zip

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The library is not in the linker's library search path.

The `target_link_libraries` command is is very straightforward: It simply passes on all of its arguments to the linker without bothering whether any of those libraries actually exist.

In your case, the `GLFW_276` library is missing (and possibly the `GLEW_190` as well, since the error occurs before that one is being processed). Make sure the library is actually installed on your system and its filename actually matches the name you use here (eg. `libGLFW_276.so`).

Once you verify that you have the required file, you need to make sure that the linker is able to find it. If the file is not located in one of the standard directories, use either [`link_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3alink_directories) to add its location to the search path, or [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3afind_library) to obtain the full path to the library file, which can then be given to `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: If the library is a dynamic library (.so, not .a) then the executable will need to be able to find the library, too. If the library isn't in a typical system-wide library directory, there are two ways to let it know where the library is: run it with LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable set to the proper directory or bake in the proper directory during linking (see man ld:/^ *-rpath).